Error installing dlib, Cmake not found in venv directory despite being installed already
I have installed Cmake through pip install Cmake, along with wheel and numpy.
When trying to install dlib using pip install dlib i get the error:
PS G:\WORK\EncroFace> pip install dlib --verbose
Using pip 24.0 from G:\WORK\EncroFace\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Running command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-69.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
  Using cached setuptools-69.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (821 kB)
  Using cached wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
  Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
  Successfully installed setuptools-69.2.0 wheel-0.43.0
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
  <string>:210: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  <string>:211: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  <string>:212: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  running egg_info
  writing tools/python\dlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to tools/python\dlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to tools/python\dlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'tools/python\dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'tools\python\build*'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'dlib\cmake_utils\*\build*'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'dlib\test'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
  writing manifest file 'tools/python\dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Running command Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml)
  <string>:210: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  <string>:211: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  <string>:212: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  running dist_info
  creating C:\Users\benjamin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-oiqzlulr\dlib.egg-info
  writing C:\Users\benjamin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-oiqzlulr\dlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to C:\Users\benjamin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-oiqzlulr\dlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to C:\Users\benjamin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-oiqzlulr\dlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
  writing manifest file 'C:\Users\benjamin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-oiqzlulr\dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file 'C:\Users\benjamin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-oiqzlulr\dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'tools\python\build*'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'dlib\cmake_utils\*\build*'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'dlib\test'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
  writing manifest file 'C:\Users\benjamin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-oiqzlulr\dlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  creating 'C:\Users\benjamin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-oiqzlulr\dlib-19.24.4.dist-info'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Running command Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml)
  <string>:210: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  <string>:211: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  <string>:212: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
    File "G:\WORK\EncroFace\venv\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'

  ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: 'G:\WORK\EncroFace\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'G:\WORK\EncroFace\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\benjamin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjicuj8sb'
  cwd: C:\Users\benjamin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8curvry1\dlib_b75c506e5565413494e9496a676891ed
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
PS G:\WORK\EncroFace>

Looking through my venv directory i can see the cmake files are installed, am I missing another prerequisite? everything online has said that this should work.
Ive been working in VScode, python version 3.12.2
ive tried installing Cmake directly from their website and uninstalling and reinstalling the python module.
you can see the cmake files in my venv directory
it also shows up when i pip list:
PS G:\WORK\EncroFace> pip list
Package         Version
--------------- --------
build           1.2.1   
cmake           3.29.0.1
colorama        0.4.6   
numpy           1.26.4  
packaging       24.0    
pip             24.0    
pyproject_hooks 1.0.0   
setuptools      69.2.0  
wheel           0.43.0  
PS G:\WORK\EncroFace> 

any help would be greatly appreciated.

first install cmake inside your venv using pip install cmake
then try installing dilb using binaries
https://github.com/z-mahmud22/Dlib_Windows_Python3.x
find the suitable file for your python version and follow the installation guide
remember to paste the whl file inside your project folder before executing the command
screenshot refer this image
